# Display items (TextView, ImageView etc) on timers in Android

Tags: android

I'm fairly new to android and was wondering if in my activity I can display different text views for a certain amount of seconds before they vanish, replaced with a different text view.

Is there any way I can handle these events within an activity? I am creating a simple game and would like the Views in the activity to display after one another.

I could not find any help online (may have been searching for the wrong thing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely use a timer variable to keep track of time and then use the `setVisibility()` method to set the textview visible(`View.VISIBLE`) or invisible(`View.INVISIBLE`).

For example:

```
    TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```